# How to use opencv to consume the UI of an android emulator/device

Tags: android, opencv

I want to use opencv to analysis the UI and send different commands to the device or emulator.

Now I am use adb screenrecord to record the video and use opencv to analysis offline, just wondering is that possible to analysis the UI on the fly?

Comment: Why do you want to use OpenCV for analysis and then send commands, is this for some type of automated UI testing? The majority of automated UI testing should be done using the proper frameworks but I can see use for OpenCV when you app displace say a Image in the UI and you want to check with OpenCV that the Image is the right Image.

Comment: Yes, The general framework can control the app elements, it running more like a white box testing. We want run all the interactives like a black box testing. Any suggestions?